# How do I concatenate and rename split file pairs with a loop?

Tags: bash, loops

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
S-100-1-54359386-left.fastq.gz
S-100-1-54469454-left.fastq.gz
S-20-1-54356384-left.fastq.gz
S-20-1-54468477-left.fastq.gz
S-40-1-54343370-left.fastq.gz
S-40-1-54465479-left.fastq.gz
S-100-2-54359386-left.fastq.gz
S-100-2-54469454-left.fastq.gz
S-20-2-54356384-left.fastq.gz
S-20-2-54468477-left.fastq.gz
S-40-2-54343370-left.fastq.gz
S-40-2-54465479-left.fastq.gz
```

Each pair of consecutive files need to be concatenated and given a unique name.  I can use the following for each pair:

```
zcat S-40-2-54343370-left.fastq.gz S-40-2-54465479-left.fastq.gz | \
gzip -c > S-40-2.left.fq.gz
```

...but I would like something more elegant.  Notice that the number after the second dash also changes.  The number after the third dash (54359386, etc.) makes each file unique, but doesn't need to be preserved after they are concatenated.  Any advice?  I'm not sure how to make a loop structured to identify the pairs.

Comment: ok, what is the problem? the concatenation or the name or both?

Comment: I want to loop through the files, find each pair, and concatenate them.  Problem is identifying pairs to pass to zcat.

Comment: Put all the filenames into an array, and iterate through the array 2 elements at a time to get the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each group can contain only 2 files.

complex pipeline:

```
echo S-*.fastq.gz | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -t'-' -k1,3n | xargs -n2 bash \
-c 'fn=$(cut -d"-" -f1-3 <<<$0)".left.fq.gz"; zcat "$0" "$1" | gzip -c > "$fn"'
```

---

- `sort -t'-' -k1,3n` - sort file list by the first 3 fields treating `-` as field separator
- `-n2` - *xargs* option, tells to use at most 2 arguments per command line